# Is there a difference between “antithesis” and “juxtaposition”?

Tags: meaning, differences

My question is as simple as the title, is there a difference between the two words. In my searching, I have found nothing yet, and it seems strange to have two words with not even a difference in connotation.

Comment: When you juxtapose two or more things, you place them next to each other, usually for comparison.  An antithesis is the opposition or contrast between two or more things.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81689/what-is-the-correct-term-for-this-juxtaposition-of-words

Comment: @Josh61 Wow, I have never heard of that word before. I like it. Thanks

Comment: In the sense of rhetorical devices, antithesis is a specific case of juxtaposition, where the two entities being juxtaposed are opposites, and are presented in a parallelism. "Hatred stirs up strife, but love conquers all offenses". Love and hate are being juxtaposed in this classic example of rhetorical antithesis. You can have juxtaposition without antithesis, e.g. "better late than never" (the antithesis of late is early, not never).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why they seem the same to you.
To my they are quite different. I am non native but let me attempt an explanation (this is made up).

I can say that my brother is just my **antithesis** when it comes to food preferences. While he likes a lot meat, I am a vegetarian.

As to juxtaposition. Yesterday I wrote some code. Then I made some changes. Then I realized I wanted to restore some parts of the previous version. Fortunately,  I had a useful software which allowed to look at the two code versions **juxtaposed**, and that helped me a lot to undo only the changes I did not really want.

(Please, do correct if I got something wrong  :-) )

Comment: So you think juxtaposition is about looking at two similar things at their differences, and antithesis is about looking at two very different things at their differences?

Comment: juxtaposition, I think, is more like placing things side by side (for instance, to compare). Antithetic is said of something which is just the "opposite" of something else.

Comment: Ok, I can see that connotation. In the literary sense, several of my teachers said the words were interchangeable, and may as well be synonyms.

Comment: To me it looks like pretty different meaning. However, it is probably possible to find instances where they may be perhaps interchanged, but I would actually need to think a bit to find an example. For more help, it's probably better to wait for opinion of a native :-)

Comment: They can be with elements of literature and poetry. From the authors point of view, the two objects are juxtaposed, as he places them side by side. From inside the poem, they both actually exist and one is a juxtaposition of the other.

Comment: Hmm. Well, in that case, it sounds more like a figurative use of the word. To have two characters which are in juxtaposition, does not seem to be the same as saying they are the antitheses of each other. For instance, one could be tragic and the other one comic, without necessarily being in antithesis. Maybe.  :-)

Comment: +1 It may help to think **geometrically**: adjacent (juxtaposed) vs opposite (antithetical/opposed).